# why scope resolution operator giving error outside the class?

Tags: c++

I want to use operator overloading outside the class. I read in documents that when we use it outside the class we can give two objects as arguments.When I define it outside the class using scope resolution operator it is giving me error. I want to know the reason

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
int L;
int B;

Rectangle()    //default constructor
{
    L = 2;
    B = 2;
}

Rectangle(int l,int b)      //parametrized constructor
{
    L = l;
    B = b;
}   
void Display()
{
cout<< "length is " << L <<endl;
cout<< "breadth is " << B <<endl;
}                             

};

Rectangle Rectangle:: operator+ (Rectangle obj1,Rectangle obj2)    
{
Rectangle obj3;

obj3.L = obj1.L + obj2.L;
obj3.B = obj1.B + obj2.B;
return obj3;

}

int main()
{
Rectangle R1;
R1.Display();

Rectangle R2(5,3);
R2.Display();

Rectangle R3 ;
R3 = R1+ R2;
R3.Display();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: for binary operators, you can either declare as a member function with one argument or as a 'free function' with two.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it. The two-argument form is actually a free function, which will be found by ADL, not a member:

```
Rectangle operator+ (Rectangle obj1,Rectangle obj2)    
{
Rectangle obj3;

obj3.L = obj1.L + obj2.L;
obj3.B = obj1.B + obj2.B;
return obj3;

}
```